# Why am I only getting the first array element returned?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I am trying to return an array of arrays from Node https server. All I am getting on the client is the first array element. Here is the client code:

```
handleItemList() {
    document.getElementById(`itemListBtn`).addEventListener(`click`, () => {
        this.setDivDisplay(`itemListDiv`);
        fetch(document.url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'x-requested-with': 'fetch.1',
                'mode': 'no-cors'
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response.text();
        }).then(function (data) {
            console.log(data); //outputs 1st MD array element only!
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    });
}
```

Here is the server code:

```
if (request.headers['x-requested-with'] === 'fetch.1') {
    this.data_handler.getAllItems(function (fetchedData) {
        console.log(fetchedData); //outputs entire MD array! (as string)
        response.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
        response.end(fetchedData);
    });
}
```

Here is the DataHandler class method:

```
getAllItems(callback) {
        this.db.all(`SELECT * FROM psp_assets`, function(err, rows) {
            rows.forEach(function (row) {
                let data = [row.maker, row.model, row.tag, row.sn, row.type, row.description, row.warranty, row.purchaseDate, row.isTitle1, row.isTitle9, row.is31a];
                callback(JSON.stringify(data));
            });
        });
    }
```

Here is some sample data in the MD array:

```
["Samsung","srfg Quasi Turbo Monitor",223456,"223344","lcd_monitor","someting",24,"2016-01-20",1,0,0]
["LG","AQ 2013",226122,"345678","lcd_monitor","Monitor",36,"2015-01-03",0,1,0]
["Asus","FG3098",87654,"123987","lcd_monitor","Monitor",12,"2016-04-02",0,0,1]
["Apple","iPad Pro",7654321,"654321","ipad","iPad",12,"2016-01-20",1,0,0]
["Logitech","Cam223",678345,"3456789","consumable","WebCam",6,"2016-01-23",1,0,0]
["HP","Stream Pro G4",76534,"87654321","laptop","Mini lapto",12,"2016-01-20",1,0,0]
["hp","Stream 11 G4 Pro EE",878787,"89743211","laptop","laptop",24,"2017-03-03",0,1,0]
```

Comment: You need to create a JSON string server side, and then use JSON to parse it client side. Did you do that?

Comment: also can you expose your MD array 's format please ...

Comment: That data is not valid as a JSON string, should be a comma after each array.

Comment: And you need to run `JSON.stringify()` on the whole, outer array, not on each inner.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! It was because of the code I had in the `dataHandler()` method. Here is the new method which pushes the data into the array.

```
getAllItems(callback) {
        this.db.all(`SELECT * FROM psp_assets`, function(err, rows) {
            let data = [];
            rows.forEach(function (row) {
                data.push([row.maker,row.model,row.tag,row.sn,row.type,row.description,row.warranty,row.purchaseDate,row.isTitle1,row.isTitle9,row.is31a]);
            });
            callback(data);
        });
    }
```